# Может ли одновременно использоваться две системы инициализации?

Tags: linux

У меня Linux Mint 17.3 .

Некоторые из демонов инициализируются при помощи init, некоторые при помощи upstart.

К примеру, демон Preload у меня запускается при помощи init. Ссылка присутствует в /etc/rcN.d, а его config файл для upstart отсутствует. Также в выводе команды `initctl list` демон preload отсутствует. При всем этом `service preload status` говорит что `preload is running`.

Но такие демоны как mdm не имеют ссылок на себя в /etc/rcN.d, но имеют config файлы для upstart в /etc/init. И тоже запускаются при старте.

**Вопрос:** как так получается? Ведь процесс инициализации получает PID 1. Кажется ведь что он должен быть только один.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> К примеру, демон Preload у меня запускается при помощи init

да, с «помощью» программы `/sbin/init`, которая, как вы можете видеть, в вашем случае принадлежит пакету *upstart*.

ею же и выполняются команды из конфигурацинных файлов `/etc/init/*`. один из них — это `/etc/init/rc.conf` (понятно, тоже из пакета *upstart*), в котором запускается скрипт `/etc/init.d/rc` (из пакета `sysv-rc`, который собирается из тех же исходников, что и пакет `sysvinit`), который, уже в свою очередь, выполняет нужные файлы (точнее, symlink-и) из соответствующих каталогов `/etc/rc?.d/`, передавая параметрами `start` либо `stop`.

> Также в выводе команды initctl list демон preload отсутствует

в этом списке отнюдь не «демоны» перечислены, а (цитирую) «known jobs and instances». см. описание команды *list* в `man initctl`.

> При всем этом service preload status говорит что preload is running

если вы заглянете в файл `/usr/sbin/service` (из пакета `sysvinit-utils`, который тоже собирается из тех же исходников, что и `sysvinit`), то увидите, что, при необходимости, он «забирается» в тот самый каталог `/etc/init.d/`, ищет там соответствующий файл и запускает его с переданным параметром (в данном случае — `status`).

> как так получается? Ведь процесс инициализации получает PID 1. Кажется ведь что он должен быть только один.

«как так получается» я, надеюсь, растолковал выше.

по поводу процесса «номер 1»: это единственный процесс, который запускает *непосредственно* программа *linux* (и при внезапном завершении которого программа *linux* «впадает» в *kernel panic*). да, вполне логично, что именно этот процесс при запуске осуществляет дальнейшие необходимые для работы операционной системы операции. в частности, запускает всяких разных «демонов». а что именно запускается — зависит от логики работы этой программы и от её текущей конфигурации. и процесс этот (по крайней мере в начале) — «лавинообразный»: та или иная запущенная программа может порождать запуск ещё кучи других программ и так далее.

в принципе, ничто не мешает вам, к примеру, указать программе *linux* параметр `init=/bin/bash`, дождаться приглашения оболочки, и вручную запустить всё, что вам необходимо: и программу *preload*, и все прочие сервисы, и получить в итоге практически точно так же функционирующую систему, как будто вместо вас всем этим занималась программа `/sbin/init` (и запущенные ею программы).

---

**дополнение**

вероятно, не совсем правильно называть процесс номер 1 «процессом инициализации». этот процесс занимается не только инициализацией, но и принимает самое непосредственное участие как в дальнейшей работе операционной системы (например, тот же самый *sysv*-стильный переход между *runlevel-ами*) так и в завершении её работы.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за столь внятное объяснение. Я провел небольшой эксперимент. Я удалил из папки /etc/init файл ssh.config
Но добавил при помощи sysv-rc-conf добавил symlink-и в rcN.d папки со второго по пятый включительно. В этом случае, как мне думалось, /etc/init.d/rc скрипт должен был бы запустить ssh демон. Но этого не произошло. Более того он теперь даже так не запускается sudo /etc/init.d/ssh start. Почему так происходит?

Comment: посмотрите в текст файла: при любом параметре первым делом выполняется функция (в том же файле) `check_for_upstart()`, которая, вероятно, проверяет наличие *upstart*-а и при обнаружении завершает работу скрипта.

Comment: да :) в точку. 

Я тут у себя папку etc/systemd обнаружил. Это какая то заглушка?

Comment: посмотрите, какому пакету принадлежит каталог. `dpkg -S /путь/к/файлу/или/каталогу`.

Comment: systemd-services

Comment: вот и ответ. если у вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы. комментарии не предназначены для длинных дискуссий.